# Display all images from a URL to my Android app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio. I'm trying to design an activity where, given a URL, I can click on some button that allows me to extract the first 20 images that it finds on the webpage.

Is there some way to do this in Java without a library?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using web page url then use **webview** class in android.here is the website document
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView

otherwise you creating own layout then use 2 famous dependencies:

```
1.Glide
2.Picasso
```

Comment: You need AsyncTask for this

Answer (score 0):

You need Asynctask

1. create a Bitmap variable
2. open an InputStream with the url that is passed
3. use BitmapFactory.decodeStream() on the InputStream
4. assign it to the created Bitmap variable
5. Then in the onPostExecute method, you simply use setImageBitmap on the ImageView

-->

```
private class DownloadImageFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void,Bitmap> {
            ImageView bmImage;
            public DownloadImageFromUrl(ImageView bmImage) {
                this.bmImage = bmImage;
            }
        
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String urldisplay = urls[0];
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bmp;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
```